# Displaying div hash when modal is displayed with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that triggers a modal window to show up. Because of `data-toggle="modal"` the url is not changed to `www.doman.com/index.html#modalDiv`, and I need it to change.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Only thing that comes to my mind is to have a script that will add the hash to the url, but I was wondering if there is simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will have to override the default handling of data-modal, since its code in Bootstrap includes a `return false`.

You will have to create your own workaround. Something like:

Remove `data-toggle="modal"` and add a class of `launch-modal` to the `<a>` element

Then some javascript:

```
$('a.launch-modal').click(function (e) {
    var modalId = $(this).attr('href');
    $(modalId).show();
});
```